# Greenplum PSQL Format for Dynamic Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, format, psql, greenplum

Firstly, thank you in advance for any help with my relatively simple issue below. It's honestly driving my insane!

Simply, I'm trying to select some metrics on all tables in a schema. However, this specifically includes Partitioned tables in Greenplum (which, for those who don't know it, have a single parent table named X and then child tables named X_1_prt_3, X_1_prt_4, etc).

As a result, my query in trying to get the total table size for the single partitioned table X is as follows:

```
-- Part 1
select cast(sum(sotaidtablesize) as bigint) / 1024 / 1024 as "Table Size (MB)"
from gp_toolkit.gp_size_of_table_and_indexes_disk
where sotaidschemaname = 'Y'
and sotaidtablename like 'X%'
;
```

This sums up the table size for any table named X or similar thereafter, which is effectively what I want. But this is just a part of a bigger query.. I don't want to actually specify the schema and table, I want it to be:

```
-- Part 2
where sotaidschemaname = t4.nspname
and sotaidtablename like 't4.relname%'
```

but that sadly doesn't just work (what a world that would be!!). I've tried the following, which I think is close, but I cannot get it to return any value other than NULL :

```
-- Part 3
and sotaidtablename like quote_literal(format( '%I', tablename )::regclass)
```

where tablename is a column from another part (I already use this column in another format which correctly works, so I know this bit in particular isn't the issue).

Thank you in advance to anyone for any help!

Regards,
Vinny

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier using `gp_size_of_table_and_indexes_disk.sotaidoid` on the join clause rather than `(sotaidschemaname, sotaidtablename)`.

For example:

```
SELECT pg_namespace.nspname AS schema,
    pg_class.relname AS relation, 
    pg_size_pretty(sotd.sotdsize::BIGINT) as tablesize, 
    pg_size_pretty(sotd.sotdtoastsize::BIGINT) as toastsize, 
    pg_size_pretty(sotd.sotdadditionalsize::BIGINT) as othersize, 
    pg_size_pretty(sotaid.sotaidtablesize::BIGINT) as tabledisksize, 
    pg_size_pretty(sotaid.sotaididxsize::BIGINT) as indexsize 
FROM pg_class 
    LEFT JOIN pg_stat_user_tables 
        ON pg_stat_user_tables.relid = pg_class.oid 
    LEFT JOIN gp_toolkit.gp_size_of_table_disk sotd 
        ON sotd.sotdoid = pg_class.oid 
    LEFT JOIN gp_toolkit.gp_size_of_table_and_indexes_disk sotaid 
        ON sotaid.sotaidoid = pg_class.oid 
    LEFT JOIN pg_namespace 
        ON pg_namespace.oid = pg_class.relnamespace 
WHERE 
    pg_class.relkind = 'r'
    AND relstorage != 'x'                       
    AND pg_namespace.nspname NOT IN ('information_schema', 'madlib', 'pg_catalog', 'gptext') 
    AND pg_class.relname NOT IN ('spatial_ref_sys');
```